# Substring index out of bounds even though index < string.Length

Tags: indexing, substring, bounds

I'm trying to get a substring from a big string of data that I have, but when I use this line:

```
string output = datastring.substring(0, datastring.Length-1)
```

it tells me that the index is out of bounds ("Index and length must refer to a location within the string").

This worked just fine, such that outputstring printed out as the same thing as the datastring

```
while (index < datastring.Length)
        {
            outputstring += datastring[index];
            index++;
        }
```

However, this gives me an error:

```
if (index + 10 < datastring.Length)
{
      if (datastring.substring(index, index+10) == "name")
      {
            outputstring += " found instance of 'name'";

      }      

}
```

It says that the index is out of bounds. How can the index be out of bounds in the second 'if' statement when I already checked that index+10 was within range?

Answer (score 0):

It's `.substring(offset, length)`, not `.substring(startOffset, endOffset)`.

Instead of

```
datastring.substring(index, index+10)
```

use

```
datastring.substring(index, 10)
```